# Unity C# Delegate for an AJAX call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an Unity project using C# and know that WWW object would do similar thing to HTTP. WWW, however, does not provide callback function, so I create my own class which provide delegate.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WebAccess : MonoBehaviour {
    private WWW     www;

    public delegate void OnRspnReady(WebAccess webAccess);  // Response ready callback
    public delegate void OnRspnErr(WebAccess webAccess);    // Response error callback
    private void noOp(WebAccess webAccess){}    // no operation

    public WebAccess(){}

    // create a new customised request
    public  void    sendReq(string uri){
        this.sendReq(uri, noOp, noOp);
    }
    public  void    sendReq(string uri, OnRspnReady onRspnReady){
        this.sendReq(uri, onRspnReady, noOp);
    }
    public  void    sendReq(string uri, OnRspnReady onRspnReady, OnRspnErr onRspnErr){
        this.www = new WWW(uri);
        StartCoroutine(waitForReq(this.www, onRspnReady, onRspnErr));
        // return this.www.responseHeaders.ToString();
    }

    // get Response content
    public WWW  getWWW(){
        return this.www;
    }

    private IEnumerator waitTillDone(){
        while(!this.www.isDone){}
        yield return null;
    }

    private IEnumerator waitForReq(WWW www, OnRspnReady onRspnReady, OnRspnErr onRspnErr) {
        yield return www;

        // check for errors
        if (www.error == null){
            // Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
            onRspnReady(this);
        } else {
            // Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
            onRspnErr(this);
        }  
    }
}
```

I try it with the following code and get a positive result:
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        WebAccess  webAccess = GameObject.Find("Programs").transform.FindChild("WebAccess").GetComponent<WebAccess>();

        WebAccess.OnRspnReady fn = new WebAccess.OnRspnReady(rspnReadyCallBack);

        webAccess.sendReq("http://localhost", fn);
    }

    private void rspnReadyCallBack(WebAccess webAccess){
        Debug.Log(string.Concat("Main: ", webAccess.getWWW().text));
    }
}
```

As I am used to program in Javascript, creating independent function, *rspnReadyCallBack*, is a little bit troublesome. My question is - how I create a delegate function as I would do callbacks in Javascript?
For example, this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but I am very surprised there is no answer here.

You don't create a delegate using `new` and pass something to it. A delegate is rather simply a signature-blueprint (kinda like an interface but) for methods.

For now you only have defined the delegate **types** but there are no fields corresponding to them.

So in your WebAccess class you would rather have e.g.

```
public delegate void RspnReadyDelegate(WebAccess webAccess);  
public RspnReadyDelegate OnRspnReady; // Response ready callback

public delegate void RspnErrDelegate(WebAccess webAccess);    
public RspnErrDelegate OnRspnErr; // Response error callback
```

And then you either simply assign it like in your case

```
WebAccess.OnRspnReady = rspnReadyCallBack;
```

or use an anonymous function / lambda expression actually pretty similar to JavaScript

```
WebAccess.OnRspnReady = (webAccess) => 
{
    Debug.Log($"Main {webAccess.getWWW().text)}");
};
```

---

Though it would be more recommendable to use events instead of simple delegate fields everyone could overwrite at any moment.

```
public event RspnReadyDelegate OnRspnReady; // Response ready callback   
public event RspnErrDelegate OnRspnErr; // Response error callback
```

and then rather attach callbacks using `+=` and invoke the event using

```
OnRspnReady?.Invoke(this);
```